# Future passive infinitive tense?

Tags: infinitives

I'd like to know that if there any tense called future passive infinitive like past passive infinitive. If so, could you give some examples?

Past passive infinitive examples:

> **1**. I'm happy to have been invited
>
> **2.** It was appeared to have been won the match.

Comment: Something like, "I will be happy if I am going to be invited"?

Comment: ***The match appeared to have won***. Please note: these are called TO-infinitives. Please see this: http://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/verbs-followed-infinitives/ and then this: ww.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/infinitive/

Comment: @Lambie: I think you missed out ***been*** there. The best I can come up with for your sequence is something like: *We conducted an online poll to identify smokers' favourite accessory. For a while **the match appeared to have won**, but after a flurry of last-minute votes by Ronson-sponsored bots, the lighter topped the poll*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Yes, I missed been: The match appears to have BEEN won. Thanks!

Comment: @Lambie: I still think I deserve brownie points for figuring out a context where it *could* be grammatical! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, No, it interferes with my explanation. And I might just delete it the mistake. I have to think about it. If this were among English speakers only, I wouldn't mind at all. That is how it feels to me, anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second sentence is ungrammatical; I assume it means

> **2.** The match appeared to have been won.

For your question, I don't think "future" and "infinitive" go well together. It goes well with the past because the past is expressed with the auxiliary "have", hence "to have (been)" works. But the future is expressed with the modal "will", and "to will (be)" is impossible.

That said, you could use "to be going to" and finagle a pretty tortuous sentence out of it:

> She seems to be going to be invited.

While I can imagine this being uttered in hasty conversation (perhaps as live sports commentary for "The match appears to be going to be won by the Blackhawks!"), I think most people would use this periphrastic strategy:

> It seems that she's going to be invited.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the present perfect to describe an event in the future which is earlier than another event in the future on which it has some bearing or to which it is relevant.

> She *will be  delighted*  <sup>future</sup> *to have been invited*  <sup>pres. perf. pass. inf.</sup>  to join the faculty.

There is an ambiguity, however, which context must clear up.  We do not know whether the invitation has already been made at the time of that utterance (she just doesn't know about it yet) or if the speaker is looking forward to a time when the invitation will have been made.

Comment: I don't know if I'm just unimaginative, or whether there's some syntactic/semantic *reason*, but I found it fairly difficult to think of a simple context where you could combine these tenses if the second element definitely hasn't happened yet (but isn't in abeyance; it definitely *will* happen). *I must ring him at 3 am. He will be annoyed to have been woken up, as I'm sure he will tell me when he answers the phone.*

Comment: Once the pump is primed, I'm sure your imagination will kick in. *We can hide it under this bush, and it will appear to have been stolen.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  Are there any books which cover these kinds of English tenses? If so, could you please mention the names of the books?

Comment: @Yasmika Saubhagya: we do not recommend particular books here on this site, but if you are looking for a guide to help you speak and write the language, rather than a theoretical/academic approach to the tense system, you could Google "practical English usage".